# Adding user list to the Disc usage command

Tags: bash, unix

I am using this command usually to get the size of folders in my network drive:

```
du -b --max-depth=3 > folder_size.txt
```

I also need to add the username of each folder owners to the same list in the 3rd column. Anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be straightforward:

```
cut -f2 folder_size.txt | while read f; do ls -ld "$f" | cut -d' ' -f3; done > folder_owner.txt
paste -d "\t" folder_size.txt folder_owner.txt > folder_so.txt
```

1. Iterate over your file and get owner for each directory. Write it to a separate file (of the number of lines).
2. Join 2 files on a line-by-line basis.